# Preparing Ordinal and Nominal Features for classification using OneHotEncoder in scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I want to prepare a dataset that contains continuous, nominal and ordinal features for classification. I have some workaround below, but I am wondering if there is a better way using `scikit-learn`'s encoders?

Let's consider the following example dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['green', 'M', 10.1, 'class1'], ['red', 'L', 13.5, 'class2'], ['blue', 'XL', 15.3, 'class1']])
df.columns = ['color', 'size', 'prize', 'class label']
df
```

[image]

Now, the class labels can be simply converted by a label encoder (the classifier ignores order in the class labels).

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
class_le = LabelEncoder()
df['class label'] = class_le.fit_transform(df['class label'].values)
```

And I would convert the ordinal feature column `size` like so:

```
size_mapping = {
           'XL': 3,
           'L': 2,
           'M': 1}

df['size'] = df['size'].apply(lambda x: size_mapping[x])
df
```

[image]

And finally the ordinal `color` feature:

```
color_mapping = {
           'green': [0,0,1],
           'red': [0,1,0],
           'blue': [1,0,0]}

df['color'] = df['color'].apply(lambda x: color_mapping[x])
df
```

[image]

```
y = df['class label'].values
X = df.iloc[:, :-1].values
X = np.apply_along_axis(func1d= lambda x: np.array(x[0] + list(x[1:])), axis=1, arr=X)
X

array([[  0. ,   0. ,   1. ,   1. ,  10.1],
       [  0. ,   1. ,   0. ,   2. ,  13.5],
       [  1. ,   0. ,   0. ,   3. ,  15.3]])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use DictVectorizer for the nominal encoding which makes the process cleaner. Also you can apply the 'size_maping' directly with `.map()`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['green', 'M', 10.1, 'class1'], ['red', 'L', 13.5, 'class2'], ['blue', 'XL', 15.3, 'class1']])
df.columns = ['color', 'size', 'prize', 'class label']

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
class_le = LabelEncoder()
df['class label'] = class_le.fit_transform(df['class label'].values)

size_mapping = {
       'XL': 3,
       'L': 2,
       'M': 1}

df['size'] = df['size'].map(size_mapping)

feats =df.transpose().to_dict().values()

from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
Dvec = DictVectorizer()

Dvec.fit_transform(feats).toarray()
```

returns:

```
array([[  0. ,   0. ,   1. ,   0. ,  10.1,   1. ],
       [  1. ,   0. ,   0. ,   1. ,  13.5,   2. ],
       [  0. ,   1. ,   0. ,   0. ,  15.3,   3. ]])
```

Get feature names:

```
 Dvec.get_feature_names()

 ['class label', 'color=blue', 'color=green', 'color=red', 'prize', 'size']
```

Comment: Thanks, looks a lot cleaner!

Comment: This is subtly deceptive, and demonstrates massive limitation of scikits. Not all nominal features can be vectorized like you show, yet that is what scikits requires. Here, a size can work, but say the feature is "hair color"? You'd have to scikits to extract linear relationships between a hair color of 1 vs 3. Obviously, that makes no sense, and will lead to equally nonsensical results by scikit's classifiers and regressors.